# MS Access VBA query multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two tables in Access, both have a columns named 'procedure' and 'version'
that contain String values

**Recorded training Table**

procedue____________version
PO-123_______________1
PO-123_______________2
PO-123_______________3
PO-456_______________1
PO-456_______________2

**Procedures Table**

procedue____________version
PO-123_______________4
PO-456_______________3

Recorded training Table contains all the training entered into the system over time,
while Procedures Table contains the most up to date revision for each procedure.

I need a way of checking if the 'Recorded training Table' contains a record corresponding to a record in 'Procedures Table' (ie the same procedure and correct version), and if not get the highest version for each procedure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: And what have you tried till now? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT B.procedue, B.MaxVersion, C.version AS CurrentVersion
FROM (
    SELECT A.procedure, MAX(A.version) AS MaxVersion
    FROM [Recorded training] AS A
    GROUP BY A.procedure
    ) AS B INNER JOIN Procedures AS C ON B.procedure = C.procedure
```

This is also calling: [joins](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6).

Comment: Hi Maciej Los,  Many thanks for your reply, it is much appreciated, but could you please explain the references to A, B & C ?

Comment: A, B and C is used to define alias for each table. That's all ;) If my answer was helpful, please, accept it and vote-up.
Cheers,
Maciej